# how much to keep table_open cache and what settings is available in mysql to release unwanted memory cache and table cache?

Tags: mysql

how much to keep table_open cache and what settings is available in mysql to release unwanted memory cache and table cache?
MY server has 672GB RAM windows environment server 2012
Innodb_buffer_pool_size = 450GB
Can you please suggest me what are the things need to check ?

Answer (score 0):

Each unit in `table_open_cache` is one table (not one byte).  Since you have a huge amount of RAM, the 'right' answer is probably to make it a little more than the number of tables in all the databases.

It is limited to `open_files_limit`, which, in turn, is limited by the OS.  Some OSs have an artificially low 1024, but it can be changed.

Suggest `table_open_cache_instances = 16` if your version includes that relatively new feature.

If you would like a lengthier check, please provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` after mysqld has been running for more than a day, and preferably with a realistic load.

A common mistake is setting `query_cache_size` bigger than about 50M.  The code in the QC was not designed to scale.  Anyway, most production servers run better with the QC turned off.

The buffer_pool is the main cache in RAM.  There are a number of lesser ones.  Is this what you mean by "memory cache"?

Will this server be running anything other than MySQL?  If so, you should subtract that from the 672G when posing the question.

Comment: query_cache_size is off

Comment: 'Innodb_page_size', '16384','Innodb_pages_created', '15292312','Innodb_pages_read', '152420011'
'Innodb_pages_written', '29082111'
'Innodb_row_lock_current_waits', '0'
'Innodb_row_lock_time', '106335'
'Innodb_row_lock_time_max', '51034'
'Innodb_rows_deleted', '6571985'
'Innodb_rows_inserted', '395261295'
'Innodb_rows_read', '1000948314'
'Innodb_rows_updated', '286405875'
'Innodb_num_open_files', '300'
'Innodb_data_written', '725130240'
'Innodb_log_write_requests', '1135214437'
'Innodb_log_writes', '454460'
'Innodb_os_log_written', '369411484672'

Comment: query_cache_size is off ,Bytes_received 232815028880,Bytes_sent 1151271430250
'Handler_write', '1346404623'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data', '1048533'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data', '4294262784'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed', '28998737'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total', '1048576'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests', '4172228660'
'Innodb_buffer_pool_reads', '3906424','Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free', '133084''Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests', '1723114281','Innodb_data_read', '1763889664''Innodb_data_reads', '152457769','Innodb_data_writes', '30842750'

Comment: Recheck `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and whether you are running a 32-bit version of MySQL or the OS.  You should be running 64-bit.

Comment: Yes 64bit windows server 2012R2 @Rick James , any suggestions?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ver%';`

Comment: community edition 5.7.17log ,win64 mysql @Rick James

Comment: `'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data', '4294262784' ` really smells like something is limited to 32 bits.  Please post machine readable list of all `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`